# Why is my create() Method Not Recognizing a Global Variable? - Java LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have global variables called:

```
private int currentLevel;
private int mapHeight;
```

I have a constructor for my game, where currentLevel = level entered when setScreen() method is called:

```
public ElevatorLevel(Game g, int level)
{  
    super(g, level);  
    currentLevel = level;
}
```

In my create() method, I set mapHeight to 750 * currentLevel (which starts as one), however when I try to spawn in the blades as seen below, they spawn between -200 and 300. This is because the program is not recognizing currentLevel (I am assuming), so it is multiplying it by nothing, resulting with -200.

```
public void create() 
{   
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), true);
    timeElapsed = 0;
    mapHeight = 750 * currentLevel;

    blade = new PhysicsActor();
        blade.storeAnimation( "", exTex );
        blade.setOriginCenter();
        blade.circularBoundary();
        blade.setMaxSpeed(50);
        blade.setDeceleration(50);

    bladesList = new ArrayList<PhysicsActor>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            blades = blade.clone();
            float xCoord = randomFloatGenerator(440, 20);
            float yCoord = randomFloatGenerator(mapHeight - 200, 300);
            blades.setPosition(xCoord, yCoord);
            mainStage.addActor(blades);
            bladesList.add(blades);
        }
```

[image: Here is an image to help visualize]

I also have a Label in my update(float dt) method that is set to:

```
timeLabel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);
```

As seen in the image above, currentLevel is recognized by the label, but not by mapHeight in create().
How do I get currentLevel to be recognized by the create() method?

Comment: Don't "assume" things. Simply debug your code. Check what is the value of "mapHeight" and "currentLevel" in the create method.

Comment: @RhuanKrum  mapHeight and currentLevel have no value as global variables. Once the class constructor is called in the main menu screen, currentLevel should equal 1. When I multiply 750 by currentLevel to set the value of mapHeight, it equals 0. I cannot figure out why mapHeight does not equal 750, when the constructor sets int level = 1, therefore currentLevel = 1.

Comment: Can you post the complete code of this class?

Comment: The Constructor of `ElevatorLevel` will not be called if you call `setScreen()`. The Constructor of `ElevatorLevel` will only be called if you create an Instance of this Object like: `ElevatorLevel el = new ElevatorLevel();`. If you call `setScreen()` the `show()` method in your Screen will be called but not the Constructor. Try to set the Code where you set the currentLevel in the `show()` method

Comment: @Morchul The setScreen() method was being used like this: game.setScreen(new ElevatorLevel(game, 1)). Also, turns out I got it to work myself. Will be posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the standart portrait app code that i use almost in every libgdx project. I never use create method. Instead I use constructor, this code is the most bugfree one that i could have found.

GAME OR MENU SCREEN:

```
public class TutorialScreen implements Screen    {
private OrthographicCamera camera;

public static final float WORLD_HEIGHT = 240;
public static final float WORLD_WIDTH = 135;
private Viewport viewport;
private Stage stage;

private EntryPoint game;
private AdsController adsController;





public TutorialScreen(final EntryPoint game, final AdsController adsController){

    this.adsController = adsController;
    this.game = game;

    adsController.hideBannerAd();

    float aspectRatio = (float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(aspectRatio * WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
    viewport = new FitViewport(WORLD_WIDTH , WORLD_HEIGHT,camera );
    stage = new Stage(viewport, game.batch);      

}



@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();




}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

ENTRY POINT THAT YOUR APP WILL OPEN FIRST:

```
package some.package;



public class EntryPoint extends Game {
SpriteBatch batch;
final AdsController adsController;



 public EntryPoint(final AdsController adsController ){

    this.adsController = adsController; //Interface for admob


}

@Override
public void create () {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    this.setScreen(new YourScreenClass(this,adsController)); //Above is tutorial so this would be new TutorialScreen(this,adsController)

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();

    batch.end();
    super.render();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();

}
}
```

Might have missed some curly brackets or ";" but you get the idea. This way you would not encounter any reference issues.